# The table 'table_name' is full in MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb

One of our INNODB tables contained about 350 million entries. All of a sudden, we started getting the error 'The table 'table_name' is full'. The table contains logs-like entries(click logs, basically). Since we didn't need data that was a year old, as a temporary fix I deleted about 30 million entries. However, since we are getting about 5-6 million entries everyday now, I fear that this error would crop up again.
Any thoughts on how to overcome it ?

Comment: I hope you already checked availability of hard disk space. If you already checked that,  please tell me is it a 32-bit machine or  a 64 bit machine?

Comment: Question should be on https://dba.stackexchange.com/... i think with the create table statement also..

Comment: Its a 64 bit machine. There is plenty of space available. The specs are 48 gb RAM and 757 gb SSD . The used space is 500 gb. In other words, 30 % space is available.